# Put image into Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I'm currently building a blog using Google App Engine and Python and I'd like to create a column for my posts table where to store an image. How can I upload an Image from my pc and store it into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datastore is not optimized for storing images. A better option is to store it in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/). You App Engine project will get a default bucket in GCS when you enable it, and you can use your dev console to upload files to this bucket manually or a command-line tool to upload through a terminal.

Then you need to store only an object name from the GCS in the Datastore.